# How hook_form_alter() works in Drupal?

Tags: forms

How `hook_form_alter()` works in Drupal? It will work when the form is just loaded right ?  I need to modify the form variables before submission only  . Suppose i am modifying some form variables after rendering the form and the submitting it , where i can write the code for this ?

Take an example as I have a form  `node_form()` , and I am modifying the form variables in `node_form_alter()` and processing the submission in `node_form_submit()` function . Will `node_form_alter` work on pre submission too ? Or is there any workarounds ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the code inside `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` will be run when the `$form` array is being built, and before it is rendered.

All active modules that implement one of these two hooks will have their implementations called before the `$form` array is rendered. (They will be called in sequence according to their weights).

If you need to alter or manipulate the values **being submitted** by the form, you can use one of these two mentioned hooks to include in the `$form` array your custom **#validate** or **#submit** functions, where you can perform any kind of code processing you need.

A good source for finding examples of all these functionalities is the [examples module](http://www.drupal.org/project/examples), specifically around [here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/form_example/form_example_tutorial.inc#n346).